# session id or oath token, they not interchangeable?

Tags: oauth2, php, authentication, session

Very new to Salesforce development. I used a connect app to get Oauth security token in a plugin. I am trying to call an Adobe Salesforce web service that needs a session ID. When I run my plugin I get

> [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

How do I get a session ID? I have the Oauth token and tried passing it like:

```
$ch2 = curl_init();

        //ch2 
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $sf_sig);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: bearer $access_token"));
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');


        //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch2);
            ChromePhp::log($result);

        //close connection
            curl_close($ch2);
```

This clearly isnt correct because of the log I got. Just not sure how to do the session ID. I thought a oauth token would work as well?

Answer (score 3):

Session Id values and Authorization tokens are indeed interchangeable. In fact, I often use Session Id values instead of a token when I'm mocking a quick JavaScript function in my browser. For example:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', '/services/data/v36.0/');
x.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+document.cookie.match(/sid=(.+?);/)[1]);
x.onload = function() { console.log(this.response); }
x.send(null);
```

You can use either "Bearer" or "OAuth", but it is case sensitive; your particular snippet would fail because you used **b**earer instead of **B**earer.

Comment: Makes sense but even with that change I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

What [scope](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&language=en_US) parameter did you specify during the OAuth autorize call?

To be fulling interchangable with a standard Web UI Session Id you would need to `full` scope.

Based on wanting to use it with another API I'd suggest getting the `api` scope.

Also, check that you are sending the request to the correct Salesforce pod/instance. The session id will only be valid on one. You can guess the pod identifier to some degree using the Organization ID from the start of the SessionId, but it is error prone with org migrations between pods.